# $R/I$ when $R$ is the ring of real continuous functions

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, ideals

If $R$ is the ring of all real continuous functions on $[0,1]$, I am trying to find $R/I$ where
$$I=\{f\in{R}|f(.5)=0\}$$
Showing $I$ is an ideal is not a problem since we're defining addition and multiplication as $$(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x).$$ 
$$(fg)(x)=f(x)g(x)$$but I'm trying to identify $R/I$.  I am new to ring theory and i'm having trouble with the math.  What do elements of $R/I$ look like?  I know that Ideals are analogues of normal subgroups in group theory and that normal subgroups are defined as 
$$N=\{a\in{G}|aH=Ha\}$$
where G is a group and H is a subgroup.
This makes sense to me with Ideals but I can't think of this in terms of continuous functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is that two elements $[f]$ and $[g]$ of the quotient are the same if and only if $f(0.5)=g(0.5)$. So, intuitively, what only matters for $[f]$ is only its value on $0.5$, therefore $R/I$ should be isomorphic to $\mathbb R$. Indeed, this is the case, and you can see that after considering the map Hagen von Eitzen mentioned above.

Comment: is it possible to show me the bijection?  I'm having trouble constructing.  I understand that they are isomorphic by the first homomorphism theory, but I'm having trouble seeing the injection and surjection.

Comment: If $\phi:R\to\mathbb R$ is given by $\phi(f)=f(0.5)$, then $\phi$ is a homomorphism. The kernel of $\phi$ is $I$, and if $r\in\mathbb R$, then for the constant function $f(x)=r$ you have that $\phi(f)=r$, so $\phi$ is onto. Now, use the first isomorphism theorem: $R/I$ is isomorphic to the image of $\phi$, which is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: That is good.  That really helps.

Answer (score 5):

*Hint:* What is the kernel of the ring homomorphism $R\to \mathbb R$, $f\mapsto f(0.5)$?

Comment: that would be $I$ by definition right?

Comment: Now you just need to know that $f\mapsto f(0.5)$ is onto the reals... @Iceman

Comment: So to show f is onto, we must show that given $r\in{\mathbb{R}}$ there exists an $f\in{I}$ such that $r=f(.5)$ right?

Comment: I'm really struggling with this intuitively...I think I'm understanding that this quotient ring $R/I$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ by the mapping above, but I'm simply having trouble wrapping my head around it.